# How to present hierarchical data in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have two tables `Company` and `CompanyRelationShip`.

```
DECLARE @Company TABLE (
    CompanyId INT
    ,RootCompanyId INT
    ,CompanyName VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT INTO @Company
VALUES (2,2,'ROOT')
,(106,2,'ABC')
,(105,2,'CDF')
,(3,3,'ROOT2')
,(150,3,'YXZ')
,(151,3,'XZX')


DECLARE @CompanyRelationShip TABLE (
    PrimaryCompanyId INT
    ,CompanyId INT
    )

INSERT INTO @CompanyRelationShip
VALUES (2,2)
,(2,106)
,(2,105)
,(106,105)
,(3,3)
,(3,151)
,(3,150)
,(151,150)
```

I want the result in the below format

```
CompanyId   PrimayCompanyId PrimaryCompanyName  RootCompanyId   RootCompanyName
2                 2              ROOT               2               ROOT
106               2              ROOT               2               ROOT
105              106             ABC                2               ROOT
3                 3              ROOT2              3               ROOT2
151              3               ROOT2              3               ROOT2
150              151             XZX                3               ROOT2
```

I have tried the below query to get the result

```
WITH PrimayCompany
AS (
    SELECT CR.PrimaryCompanyId
        ,C.CompanyName
    FROM @CompanyRelationShip CR
    JOIN @Company C ON CR.CompanyId = CR.PrimaryCompanyId
    )
    ,RootCompany
AS (
    SELECT RootCompanyId
        ,CompanyName
    FROM @Company
    WHERE CompanyId = RootCompanyId
    )
SELECT C.CompanyId
    ,C.RootCompanyId
    ,RC.CompanyName
    ,CR.PrimaryCompanyId
    ,PC.CompanyName
FROM @Company C
LEFT JOIN @CompanyRelationShip CR ON C.CompanyId = CR.PrimaryCompanyId
LEFT JOIN PrimayCompany PC ON PC.PrimaryCompanyId = CR.PrimaryCompanyId
LEFT JOIN RootCompany RC ON RC.RootCompanyId = CR.PrimaryCompanyId
```

I would really appreciate a bit of help.

Comment: What's the task? To get all records with root 2?

Comment: I dont get your query logic

Comment: I have modified the query. I want the details of Primary Company and Root Company of for each company from company table.

Comment: There are two PrimaryCompanyIds (2 & 106) for CompanyId 105. How would you decide which PrimaryCompanyId to take for 105?

Comment: Here 2 is RootCompanyId if we see in Company table. So for 105, 106 is Primary company.

Comment: Is there any reason for the table `@CompanyRelationship`? You might use only the first table and place 105 **below** 106 simply by setting the `RootCompanyId` accordingly.

Comment: Btw: Thank you very much for the question with a full [mcve]. This allows us to help much more *spot on* and to understand your issue...

Comment: Yes there is no need of CompanyRelationShip table. But now the structure cant be altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my comment I asked you, why you would need the table `@CompanyRelationShip` at all... This is just adding a hell of a lot of complexity and potentials for errors.

My suggestion relies on the first table alone. Look, how I've changed the parent IDs of 105 and 151 to place them **below** in the hierarchy. Just to show the principles I've added a second child **below 150**:

```
DECLARE @Company TABLE (
    CompanyId INT
    ,RootCompanyId INT
    ,CompanyName VARCHAR(100)
    );

INSERT INTO @Company
VALUES (2,2,'ROOT')
,(106,2,'ABC')
,(105,106,'CDF')
,(3,3,'ROOT2')
,(150,3,'YXZ')
,(151,150,'XZX')
,(152,150,'Second below 150');
```

--the query

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT CompanyId AS [RootId],CompanyName AS [RootName],*,1 AS HierarchyLevel FROM @Company WHERE CompanyId=RootCompanyId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rc.RootId,rc.RootName,c.*,rc.HierarchyLevel+1
    FROM @Company c
    INNER JOIN recCTE rc ON c.RootCompanyId=rc.CompanyId AND c.CompanyId<>rc.CompanyId
)
SELECT RootId
      ,RootName
      ,RootCompanyId AS [PrevId]
      ,CompanyId
      ,CompanyName
      ,HierarchyLevel 
FROM recCTE rc
ORDER BY RootId,HierarchyLevel;
```

The result

```
RootId  RootName    PrevId  CompanyId   CompanyName     HierarchyLevel
2       ROOT        2       2           ROOT                1
2       ROOT        2       106         ABC                 2
2       ROOT        106     105         CDF                 3
3       ROOT2       3       3           ROOT2               1
3       ROOT2       3       150         YXZ                 2
3       ROOT2       150     151         XZX                 3
3       ROOT2       150     152         Second below 150    3
```

The idea in short:

- We use a a *recursive CTE* (which is a rather **iterative** concept actually).
- The first SELECT (the **anchor**) starts with the companies, where the two IDs match.
- The second SELECT after UNION ALL picks the next level by **joining** to the intermediate result line
- The two columns `RootId` and `RootName` are just passed through to show up in your final set.

The `HierarchyLevel` is the position within the line, thus placing 105 **within** ROOT, but **below** 106.

Hope this helps...

### A solution for the given structure

As told, the given structure is not the best choice and should be altered. But if you have to stick to this, you might try something along this:

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT CompanyId AS [RootId],CompanyName AS [RootName],*,1 AS HierarchyLevel FROM @Company WHERE CompanyId=RootCompanyId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rc.RootId,rc.RootName,c.*,rc.HierarchyLevel+1
    FROM @Company c
    INNER JOIN recCTE rc ON c.RootCompanyId=rc.CompanyId AND c.CompanyId<>rc.CompanyId
)
SELECT rc.CompanyId
      ,rc.CompanyName  
      ,COALESCE(crs.PrimaryCompanyId,rc.RootCompanyId) AS ComputedPrevId
      ,COALESCE(c1.CompanyName,rc.RootName) AS ComputedPrevName
      ,rc.RootId
      ,rc.RootName
FROM recCTE rc
LEFT JOIN @CompanyRelationShip  crs ON rc.CompanyId=crs.CompanyId AND rc.RootCompanyId<>crs.PrimaryCompanyId
LEFT JOIN @Company c1 ON crs.PrimaryCompanyId=c1.CompanyId
ORDER BY rc.RootId,rc.HierarchyLevel;
```

This will first use a recursive CTE to find the children below their root companies and the will try to find the corresponding line in your relationship table.

If you use just `SELECT *` instead of the column list you can see the full set.
Using `LEFT JOIN` will return `NULL`, when the `ON` claus is not met.

`COALESCE` will return the first non-NULL value, so - hopefully - the one you are after.

Comment: I am getting incorrect result. For 105 PrevId should be 106.
Please look into this.

Comment: @sasibhushan, Sorry, cannot reflect this... In my answer you can see the result and it shows the expected `PrevId=106` where `CompanyId=105`... The company 105 is placed **after** 106 by setting 106 as its parent...

Comment: Sorry, I can't see PrevId=106 where companyId=105

Comment: And one more thing I can't alter the Company table structure now. So I must take the help of CompanyRelationShip table.

Comment: Sorry I am getting the result. But I can't alter the table structure.
is there any possibility of writing the query with the above data
Thank You so much for your help.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is perfect